# For $\mathcal{L}^1$-a.e. $t\in R$, Hausdorff dimension of level sets of a locally Lipschitz function $f:R^n\to R$ is $n-1$?

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory, hausdorff-dimension

Let $f:R^n\to R$ be a locally Lipchitz function. Denote $H^n$ the n-dimensional Hausdorff measure. We know that for any  $H^n$-measurable subset $A\subset R^n$, for  $\mathcal{L}^1$-a.e. $t\in R$, $A\cap f^{-1}（t)$ is $H^{n-1}$-measurable.

Thanks for Gerald Edgar's comment, I should ask: For $\mathcal{L}^1$-a.e. $t\in R$,  $f^{-1}(t)$ is empty or has Hausdorff dimension $n-1$?

Comment: A constant function is certainly locally Lipschitz.  Its level sets are either dimension $n$ or empty.  So not dimension $n-1$.   Maybe add "non-constant"?  But even then you can have the set $t$ with $f^{-1}(t) = \varnothing$ of positive measure.  So maybe: for almost all $t$, level set $f^{-1}(t)$ is empty or has dimension $n-1$?